# Scrollbar CSS IE/CHROME/FIREFOX

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, scrollbar

i've been googling my ass off here and i found out that Firefox dont support custom scrollbar css and that the only way is with jquery.

like this one: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Now i've found a few jquery plugins that does the job BUT only to `<div class="scrollbar">content here</div>` not to the **main browser scrollbar** (you know the one on the right) and i've been reading on the plugins and no one mention anything about that matter :/ and i realy need that! IF it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try put the scrollbar class on HTML- or BODY-tag

```
<html class="scrollbar">
    <body class="scrollbar">
....
```

Comment: wow... im just speechless *ofcourse* :) thanks for the tip ill try it out right away :)

Comment: sadly it didnt work cross browser :/ chrome works ok, IE dont respond at all sadly firefox doesn either... :/

Comment: it was worth a try :)